# Getting an element to follow another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not sure what to call this so that will do, right what I would like to do is find a way to get a `div` to follow another `div`.

I am using [this jquery slider](http://iframework.net/sGlide/), using this I want to connect a `div` (just a box) to the knob of the slider so it follows above with the current value for the slider.

I would give an example of this but the site I have linked has it all there and my code is elsewhere currently.

Now im not sure if there is anything like `follow()` in jquery where you can just point a element to what you want it to follow and set the distance (I have looked for something like this) so these are the ideas (that I tried and failed) I came up with to try and solve this.

- Find the slider knob's CSS live on the page and set it to the `div` (following div) so I would grab `left: 0;` from the slider knob and put this on following `div`. - Not sure if this is possible I had ago but couldn't find a way to do this.
- Change the image for the slider knob to include a box above. But I don't think I would be able to put the value onto this.

Again with all things I get stuck with, am I over thinking this? Is there an easier way to do this.

Any help with this would be great, even just pointing me in the right direction would be helpful as I have just hit a brick wall on this one.

I just set-up the basic version of it here if you want to have ago at it.

[**BASIC VERSION**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/8d9ek/)

**In short:** How can I get a `div` to sit ontop (just above) and follow of the slider knob?

`div` would look something like:

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

**Image:** This is what I want it to look like, and the `div` will follow the knob.
[image]

Comment: what is the question mate???either put question on top or bottom..helps in understanding!!! :)

Comment: Added a short question at the end.

Comment: @NoobEditor Take a look at the question, I added an image to make it clear what I'm saying. I'm counting on you to help me with this. I doubt anyone else can be asked to put effort in for this. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this one out - Updated so the follow div does not extend outside the parent's width.

http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/8/

Basic idea is...

1. Create a div to contain your "following" markup, positioned relative.
2. inside that are 2 positioned absolute elements. (1 for content and 1 for the little arrow below that)
3. The drag callback updates the "left" property of the two following elements to reflect the percentage selected with the slider.
4. those following elements have nagative margin left of half their width to keep them centered on the chosen point.

HTML:

```
<div id="follow-container">
    <div id="follow">I am following the knob below me</div>
    <div id="follow-container-inner">
        <div id="follow-arrow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="testslider"></div>
<div id="percentage"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#follow-container {
    padding: 0px 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#follow-container-inner {
    height: 55px;
    position: relative;
}

#follow {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -77px; /* half width */
    text-align: center;
}

#follow-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-top-color: #000;
    bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

And JS:

```
$('#testslider').sGlide({
    height: 10,
    image: 'knob.png',
    startAt: 70,
    colorStart: '#3a4d31',
    colorEnd: '#7bb560',
    buttons: true,
    drag: function(o){
        var pct = Math.round(o.value)+'%';
        $('#percentage').html(pct);

        // Position the follow div and arrow
        $('#follow, #follow-arrow').css('left', o.value+'%');

        // a little offsetting required to stop the elements going outside 100% width of the container
        var $follow = $('#follow');
        $follow.css('margin-left', -(Math.round(o.value)/100*$follow.outerWidth()));
    },
    onButton: function(o){
        var pct = Math.round(o.value)+'%';
        $('#percentage').html(pct);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is pretty cool but there is one thing. The `div` goes away from the slider knob when moving up and down. Anyone to get that to stick dead on the slider knob?

Comment: Very nice indeed, I will select as the correct answer as this is what I asked for. Good job! If you could help me get this perfect that would be great too. I just need the box `div` not the arrow. As the box `div` is a image with the point on it. Thats why I need the box `div` to be right ontop of the slider knob at all times so it looks apart of it. Im trying to work out how to do it using your code now. So any help would be a huge plus!

Comment: Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/9/
Although please note that the separate arrow in HTML means you can position the arrow and box content separately - which worked well in the above answer -- moving the arrow to an image will make it not aligned to the center of the knob anymore.

If you're ok with adding some padding on either side of the slider control to make room for the "follow" content to overlap, try this fiddle (it's very much simplified when compared to the above answer but sounds like it suits your needs better)
http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/10/

Comment: I can remove the arrow its just I need the box to do that the arrow was, sitting dead on top of the slider knob in the center. Im sorry about all this back and forward stuff, I really do appreciate the time and effort you are giving to help me with this.

Comment: No problem - edited my above comment with update which I think will work for you :) Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help! it still moves a little and I do need it not to but I think I can find a fix for it. When it gets to a certain percentage I will just `* 1.02` or something to cheat it and keep it on track.

Answer (score 1):

The library you're using has a `drag` callback you can pass a function to that will be called whenever the slider moves.

```
function callback(o) {
    var pos = o.el.find('.slider_knob').offset() // Grab the knob's page location
    $('#div').css({'left': pos.left, 'top': pos.top + 10}) // Shove the div right under it
}
$('#slider').sGlide({
    // Stuff
    drag: callback
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lexicality/RSULF/)

Comment: Yeah, looks like the slider library the OP was using is gone now

Answer (score 0):

check this

http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/1/

```
<div  style="text-align:center">
 <div id="test" style="display:inline-block; width:70%; vertical-align:middle;">
   <div id="testslider" class="slider_bar">
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="pct"></div>
```

New Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/2/

Redited with tooltip

http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/3

[jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/5](http://jsfiddle.net/8d9ek/5/)

Comment: he wants the slider to be on top of green line...you have just centered the layout mate!!!

Comment: Not even a little bit close and NoobEditor maybe I have not made it clear what I want let me get an image up.

Comment: Take a look at my question now. I don't know how toy got this from what I said but if I really made that little sense apologizes.

Comment: A tooltip (this is just a title) is not a `div`.

Comment: That's not a bad idea but it needs to be visible at all times and contain the value for the slider.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a regular callback for element movement, however you can tie in a check at an interval using setInterval(function, time)  that checks the offset().left or offset().top of the slider, then copies the value to the Div CSS.

Will edit with example when I'm not on mobile.